# mongoose filter array in query , i can find this in mongodb but not in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({          
       month:String,
       year:String,
       endDate:Date,
       bio:[{
           _id:false,
           id:String,
           date:Date,
           inTime:Date,
           outTime:Date,
           workingHours:String
       }],
       createdBy:ObjectId   
},{timestamps:true});

schema.index({month: 1, year: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports=mongoose.model('bioMatrix',schema);
```

i want to get only bio data whose id is say "18"
I am trying like

```
   BioMatrix.find({month:11,year:2016,'bio.id':"18"},{bio:1,_id:0})     
   .exec(function(e,b){           
       console.log(JSON.stringify(b[0]))
   })
```

But it show all the bio data wich is around 1000

How to find only filter array

also tried

```
BioMatrix.find( { bio : { $elemMatch: {  id : "18" } } })
 .exec(function(e,b){           
       console.log(e)
       console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
   })
```

Comment: As one of the answers in the marked duplicate suggests, you need to use the `$ positional operator` in your projection as `BioMatrix.find( { bio : { $elemMatch: {  id : "18" } } }, {'bio.$': 1}).exec(callback);`

Comment: it is working , but only first object of bio is coming not all

Comment: Done 

    BioMatrix.aggregate([
    { $match: {month:"10"}},
    { $project: {
        bio: {$filter: {
            input: '$bio',
            as: 'item',
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.bioId", 18 ] }
        }}
    }}
],function(err,usr){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(usr))
    })